# Docker - Adding yum install to the base image

Tags: docker

I have a base image which contains OS+JDK and building my image on top of this. I have "yum install sftp" in my Docker file right after the "FROM base image".

Now, I would like to include "yum install sftp" also to my base image, so that I don't have to have this step in my DockerFile. I do not have much experience on building base image.

Comment: What have you already tried?  What's your use case that requires `sftp` in every single image you build?

Comment: Yes, all my image needs sftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own base image is just same as your own image.

**Old:**

```
FROM openjdk:8u151
RUN yum install sftp
```

**New:**

*dockerid/baseimage*

```
FROM openjdk:8u151
RUN yum install sftp
```

*app dockerfile*

```
FROM dockerid/baseimage
```

Of course, you need to commit your base image.